# Java uploading file to AWS EC2 server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, java-8, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java

our use case needs to upload file from our on-premise server to an AWS EC2. Tried doing some research and could not find any available code samples on how to do this in Java. Has anyone done this before? and if yes and you direct me to some code template or sample codes I can use as basis.

We are using Java 8 by the way. Our EC2's VPC is connected to our on-premise network so for sure our on-premise server can see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any specific services installed on your EC2 instance and want to push files to EC2 (instead of pulling from other services like S3), you could transfer files using the SSH protocol.

You can use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is a Java library that implements SSH. There are many [examples on the jsch website](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) showing how to use jsch, also specific ones showing file transfers.

Comment: got it thanks. would this solution still work if there is an estimated of say 500-1000 file uploads per day the java program would handle?